# file compiling but not showing the returned values of function

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a piece of code. When I run this code. It is compiling but not showing any print result. I want to print the returned values from this function. Can someone please guide me where I'm wrong?

```
`def input_data(prefix):
    datafiles=os.listdir('/home/zeri/Desktop/check2')
    dictData={}
        for df in datafiles:
            if re.match(prefix,df) and 
            os.path.isfile('/home/zeri/Desktop/check2'+'/'+df):
            hmax=locale.atof(df[3:])
            print hmax
            data=np.genfromtxt(df, delimiter=' ')
            dictData[hmax]=data
        return dictData,len(data[0])
int main():
    a=input_data('xyz')
    print a`
```

Comment: `int main():` is meaningless in Python.  The only possible result of trying to run this code is a syntax error.

Comment: I tried even without int but still not showing any result.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not C. So, "int main()" does not work. Better remove this line altogether, although you can define a function called "main".

But probably you have mainly an indentation issue. I tried to fix this in the code below.

```
import locale
import numpy as np
import re

def input_data(prefix):
    datafiles = os.listdir('/home/zeri/Desktop/check2')
    dictData = {}
    for df in datafiles:
        if re.match(prefix, df) and os.path.isfile('/home/zeri/Desktop/check2' + '/' + df):
            hmax = locale.atof(df[3:])
            print hmax          # use "print(a)" if on Python 3
            data = np.genfromtxt(df, delimiter = ' ')
            dictData[hmax] = data
    return dictData, len(data[0])


a = input_data('xyz')
print a                         # use "print(a)" if on Python 3
```

By the way, I would not use regular expressions to filter files.